# Loop does not run more than once

Tags: c

The output should print the statement "Case #(N): I will become a good boy." a certain number of times depending on user input. It should only print prime numbers of N. This is the latest attempt.

```
 #include<stdio.h> 

 int main(){

 int primeNum;
 int primeCount;
 int primeCheck;
 int caseCount=1;
 int caseCheck;

 scanf("%d", &caseCheck);//gets number of cases

 do {
 scanf("%d", &primeNum);
 primeCheck = 0;
      if (primeNum<=1)
 {
 caseCount++;
 }
 for (primeCount=2 ; primeCount<=primeNum/2 ; primeCount++)//checks if number is prime
 {
      if ((primeNum%primeCount) == 0)//checks if number is not prime
      {
      primeCheck=1;
      }
 }
 if (primeCheck==0)
      printf("Case #%d: I will become a good boy.\n", caseCount);//prints if number is prime
 } while (caseCount=caseCheck);//while case counter does not exceed number of cases
 return(0);}`
```

The result of this piece of code when the output is 2 [enter] 4 [enter] 2 is "Case #2: I will become a good boy." Why does it not print more than one time and start from number 2?

Comment: `caseCount=caseCheck` in the loop is assignment, not equality check

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings: `warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression`

Comment: please indent your code properly

Answer (score 0):

Just change `while (caseCount=caseCheck);` to `while (caseCount==caseCheck);`
The problem with your code is you're not checking the condition. You're just reassigning a value to a variable.